# Need SAS Code for Data validation after delimited values

Tags: sas

i have data set like

```
Car Make Model Type Origin Seat MRP Show Room Price Rate Star
Acura|MDX|SUV|Asia|All|$36,945|$33,337|3.5|
Acura|RSX Type S 2dr|Sedan|Asia|Front|$23,820|$21,761|2|
```

result value assisgn column as per result shown

Expected Result

```
Car Make  Model                    Type    Origin  Seat    MRP      Show Room Price Rate Star 
Acura     MDX                       SUV      Asia    All   $36,945    $33,337         3.5      
Acura     RSX Type S 2dr           Sedan    Asia   Front  $23,820     $21,761          2
```

i want two code one is upload note pad file from desktop
another is assisgn in data set in data lines and input

Comment: Have you tried `Proc IMPORT` or a `DATA` step with an `INPUT` statement ?

Comment: i want code for both Import and Input statement

Comment: What have you tried? It appears that you know what you need.

Comment: Im begginner of sas learning myself from youtube so i tried to write code by getting help from forum i tried some code its not works for me?

Comment: 'DATA DELIM;
 INFILE DATALINES DLM='|';
 INPUT Car Make:$ Model $ Type $ Origin $ Seat $ MRP $ Show Room Price $ Rate Star $;
DATALINES;
Acura|MDX|SUV|Asia|All|$36,945|$33,337|3.5
Acura|RSX Type S 2dr|Sedan|Asia|Front|$23,820|$21,761|2
;
run;
PROC PRINT DATA=DELIM;
 TITLE 'CAR IMPORT';
RUN; '

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work on variable values how to assign column values even its has space like Show Room Price should be in one column